# getting grades for withdrawn students

Tags: desire2learn

We would like to use Valence to query grades/grade objects for students who have withdrawn from classes.  Our research indicates that the student's grades for a class are not deleted, but hidden when they withdraw.  We can manually view them using the D2L web interface, but would like to be able to view them using the Valence API.

Is this possible, and how?

I haven't seen anything in the Valence documentation about calls that might display withdrawn students and their objects.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework API does not provide you access to the grades of students that are not actively enrolled in a course offering. I would encourage you to [report this to Desire2Learn](http://helpdesk.desire2learn.com) as a defect through your organization's Approved Support Contact or Partner Manager.